# Trying to use Azure ARM template with object parameter but stuck with an invalid index error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am currently trying to get an Azure storage key using the following:

```
"accessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('myParameter').azureblob.storageAccountName), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]"
```

My parameter is defined as:

```
"LogicAppConnections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": [
                {
                    "storageAccountName": "myAccountName"
                }
            ]
        }
 }
```

This is the exception I am getting from the validator:

> Template validation failed: The template resource 'XYZ' at line '84' and column '9' is not valid: The language expression property 'storageAccountName' has an invalid array index.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.

Anyone knows what can be the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because its an array you have to index into it:

```
parameters('myParameter').azureblob[0].storageAccountName
```

or do this:

```
first(parameters('myParameter').azureblob)).storageAccountName
```

Comment: I don't think you want that in an array - if you pull it out of the array it will works as you have it in the OP

Comment: thats a fair observation ;)